# SSIS how to convert object to varBinary for SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dataflow

I have a csv file from csvde which has the objectGUID and some other information from AD.

I want to use SSIS to copy this info into the following table in SQL

```
[DN] [varchar](255) NULL,
[ObjectGuid] [varbinary](50) NULL,
[pwdExpiry] [bigint] NULL
```

Sample csv file from csvde file looks like this:

```
DN,objectGUID,msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
"CN=DEFRAVMDROOTCA1,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'c7eb536bc818f842bde11d8152755e7e',9223372036854775807
"CN=Sajeed Temp,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'417979aad0a9cc49818d1960ec95fb80',130834271604215531
"CN=IAMToolset.2,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'5a936d02842275458c45c1eb932a0f67',130849689154565841
"CN=IAMToolset.3,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'c03d2d11f8d8fe40a0eac70d41f3e1fd',130849689796313340
"CN=IAMToolset.4,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'e8b084e9d8c4a8428284ecb40b628da8',130849690015854425
"CN=IAMToolset.5,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'4b4e17dfce09e049941f3bd0ecddd5bb',130849690271803391
"CN=IAMToolset.6,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'004454a17c997b43af8e4b2653b491c2',130849690477125089
"CN=IAMToolset.7,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'8f70d9c64514c1409364624e3b079d42',130849690693072263
"CN=IAMToolset.8,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'ff70df18badafb4491225b29470b9a3d',130849690864329935
"CN=IAMToolset.9,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'a081e666a2df3c4481a4f124b489fdd8',130849691049650737
"CN=IAMToolset.1,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'8c59987d0a5c2a4ea1e98d07a84e1144',130849691453887596
"CN=testmigration,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'a800d0e29335d248ad990ad31fd5dd52',130732638130905654
"CN=DEFRAVMDPKMCA1,OU=Test,DC=company,DC=net",X'0d67d30bcbbbed48af9ed7736f9b1992',9223372036854775807
```

I have the SSIS package with two connection managers. One of them is for flat file and I'm reading the column objectGUID from the csv as a string. The thing is I want to convert this column inside a dataflow task to a format which I can push to the [ObjectGuid] varbinary NULL column in the SQL table.

I have use the data conversion transform and tried converting to DT_GUID and DT_BYTES but they both fail at that data conversion step when I run the package.

So what I really want to see is that if I have an objectGUID in csv file as

X'168dea153aab0a45adf8079b94041e90' (string)
I want to see it in the SQL table as 
0x168DEA153AAB0A45ADF8079B94041E90 (varBinary)

The error I get on SSIS runtime is:

```
Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: Data conversion failed while converting column "ObjectGuid.LeftCleaned" (16) to column "Copy of ObjectGuid.LeftCleaned" (6).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of ObjectGuid.LeftCleaned]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of ObjectGuid.LeftCleaned]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key is here:

> "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

Ensure you have given a large enough **Length** to the Data Conversion task to accommodate for the largest possible value in the CSV.  Also on the other side you need to make sure that the column can hold that same amount of data after conversion.

[image: DataConversionLength]

Comment: Thans Phil. I did that. That error is gone but some other error now.

Comment: I added 128 but I know they shouldn't take more than 50 in database column.